# EFs own and reverse POCO generator both skipping tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t4

Have a weird problem.

Consider the following table (SQL from SSMS 2014 create script, so no typos by me!)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRangeGroup](
    [QuestionangeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QuestionRangeGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionangeID] ASC,
    [QuestionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRangeGroup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionRangeGroup_Question] FOREIGN KEY([QuestionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRangeGroup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionRangeGroup_Question]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRangeGroup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionRangeGroup_QuestionRange] FOREIGN KEY([QuestionangeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[QuestionRange] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRangeGroup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionRangeGroup_QuestionRange]
GO
```

Both EF Reverse POCO Generator and EFs own create model from database skip this table and don't produce a model class for it.  There are a couple of other very similar that fail too.
I knocked up a very simple .tt myself to add a bunch of related classes (simple repositories to utilise the generated models) it looks like this.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
using OsipDal.EF;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace OsipDal.Repositories 
{
<#
    string connectionString = @"data source=DESKTOP-5IHV7AT\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Osip;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    DataTable schema = con.GetSchema("Tables");

    foreach(DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    { 
        var tableName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        var className = string.Format("{0}Repo", tableName.Trim());
#>
    public partial class <#= className #>: RepositoryBase<<#= tableName.Trim() #>>
    {
        public <#= className #>(DbContext context) : base(context) 
            { }
    }

<# } #>

}
```

This get's all the tables and produces classes for all of them.  Clearly not finished yet, but basically works.
A tad frustrating as the DB is currently at 40+ tables and likely to double before I'm done.  I want to iteratively create models, repositories etc as I go.  This is important as I'm not going to get the DB schema right until I'm a good way through writing my DAL and my tests are behaving as I want them to, which assures me the DB is handling what I'm trying to achieve.

Any ideas guys?  If it helps, this will be open source, once my DB and DAL are no longer embarrassing, I'll shove them up on GIT hub and let the world play/join in.

Thanks in advance guys...

J

Comment: That table looks like a Many-Many linking table. EF does not generate a model for those because it turns in it in to navigation properties (I think). Show then generated classes for `Question` and `Questionange` also any mapping it set up in the DbContext.

Comment: You are correct Sir!  I'd just realised I was being the stupid old dinosaur that I am and spotted that obvious mistake.  Now to work out the SQL to exclude those in my TT file and I'll be good to go.  Plus of course, marking this question as "lame" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding this answer because I found the question while I was searching for something else, consider changing this parameter in the Reverse POCO Generator configuration file (Database.tt) to false, if you want the Reverse POCO to generate the many-to-many mapping tables:

```
UseMappingTables = true; // If true, mapping will be used and no mapping tables will be generated. If false, all tables will be generated.
```

Hopefully it will help somebody else.